# Passing a pointer to an int array, as an argument C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, arguments

I know even if i pass an array by typing arrayname as argument (ex: getArrayInput(arrayexample); ), it will copy only the adress value of first element not entire array,still i wonder why these code gives error. I know this not the way how it should implemented but i want to understand this error.

> main.cpp|13|error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'void getArrayInput(int**)'|

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void getArrayInput(int * []);

int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter scores on by one.." << endl;
    cout<<"To terminate input enter -1"<<endl;

    int listof[10]={};
    int *ptScores =listof;
    getArrayInput(ptScores);




    return 0;
}

void getArrayInput(int * []){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        cin>>*(pt+i);
        if(*(pt+i))=-1){
            break;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Enter next.."<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to C++ where you get `std::vector<int>` for no extra charge.

Comment: By the way, you are dangerously close to overflow / out of bounds write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, arrays decay in to pointers. In some cases, they are interchangable.

`ptScores` is of type `int*` (pointer to int).
`getArrayInput` expects an `int*[]` (array of pointers to int).
`int*[]` decays in to `int**` (pointer to pointer to int).

The error says you're giving an `int*` (ptScores) to something that expects an `int**` (getArrayInput).

---

How do you fix this?
Take an `int*`.

```
void getArrayInput(int* pt){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        cin>>pt[i];
        if(pt[i]=-1){
            break;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Enter next.."<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because

```
int *
```

and

```
int[]
```

are both of type

```
int *
```

therefore, you are here asking for a

```
int **.
```

try replacing

```
void getArrayInput(int * []) by     void getArrayInput(int *)
```